# What are the differences between blue airports and green ones on the low en-route chart?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts

As far as I know, a brown airport on the low en-route chart does not have an approach procedure but blue and green airports do. But what exactly are the differences between these colors?

Answer (score 5):

From the FAA Aeronautical Chart User's Guide:

> Facilities in BLUE or GREEN have an approved Instrument Approach
>   Procedure and/or RADAR MINIMA published in either the FAA Terminal
>   Procedures Publication or the DoD FLIPs. Those in BLUE have an
>   Instrument Approach Procedure and/or RADAR MINIMA published at least
>   in the High Altitude DoD FLIPs. Facilities in BROWN do not have a
>   published Instrument Procedure or RADAR MINIMA.

So the green ones are in the FAA TPP but not in the DoD High Altitude FLIPs.